# Vue.js 3 Composition API vs. Options API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Can someone explain why this does not work with script setup, but without it works.
In the template I use `v-for` to iterate through the string[]:

```
<div v-for="lang in data.translatedLanguages" class="translationTableBodyRow">
      <div class="translationTableBodyCell">xx</div>
      <div class="translationTableBodyCell">{{ lang }}</div>
      <div class="translationTableBodyCell">10 %</div>
      <div class="translationTableBodyCell">Edit</div>
</div>
```

Code with `<script lang="ts">`:
Working, the `v-for` finds elements and I see the rows.

```
<script  lang="ts">
import axios, {isCancel, AxiosError} from 'axios';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            data: { translatedLanguages: [] }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get("https://translation.colreminder.com/test/data.php?request=langTranslated").then(response => {
            console.log(response.request.response);
            this.data = JSON.parse(response.request.response)
            this.data.translatedLanguages
            console.log(this.data.translatedLanguages);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Script with `<script setup lang="ts">`:
Not working, I don't see any rows because `v-for` seems does not find the elements, but the data object is not empty.

```
<script lang="ts">
import axios, {isCancel, AxiosError} from 'axios';
import { onMounted, reactive, VueElement } from 'vue';
import type { LanguagesTranslated } from './main';

var data: LanguagesTranslated = { translatedLanguages: [] };

onMounted(() => {
    axios.get("https://translation.colreminder.com/test/data.php?request=langTranslated").then(response => {
        console.log(response.request.response);
        data = JSON.parse(response.request.response);
        console.log(data.translatedLanguages);
    });
});
</script>
```

LanguagesTranslated is this interface:

```
export interface LanguagesTranslated {
    translatedLanguages: string[];
}
```

Comment: [Documentation for <script setup></script>](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html)

Comment: Thanks @jackssrt, I know the documentation.

Comment: With script setup, unlike the option api, variables are not reactive by default. You have to use `ref` or `reactive` wrappers to make it reactive, so your template can react to their changes.

Comment: You are not asking about `<script setup>` specifically, but the Composition API vs the Options API. Could you please edit your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example is using the Options API. When using the Options API, properties in the object returned by `data()` are made reactive automatically.

The `setup()` function and `<script setup>` are the two ways of using the Composition API. When using the Composition API, your acts more like normal JavaScript. To create a reactive variable, you have to explicitly create it using one of the Reactivity API functions: `ref()`, `reactive()`, or `computed()`.

As your example with `<script setup>` is creating a plain variable, it is not reactive and the `v-for` does not re-evaluate when you reassign it.

Try this:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import axios, { isCancel, AxiosError } from 'axios';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import type { LanguagesTranslated } from './main';

// Use `ref` here to create a Ref.
const data = ref<LanguagesTranslated>({ translatedLanguages: [] });

onMounted(() => {
    axios
        .get("https://translation.colreminder.com/test/data.php?request=langTranslated")
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.request.response);
            // Use `data.value`, as `data` is a Ref.
            data.value = JSON.parse(response.request.response);
            console.log(data.value.translatedLanguages);
        });
});
</script>
```